# What is the function/meaning of "thus understood" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

> The obvious paradox which makes the thesis of man’s animal origin
> **thus understood** actually serve idealism has already been pointed out by A. Leroi-Gourhan. Haunted by the idea of the ape-man, the
> paleontology and prehistory of the nineteenth century and the
> beginning of the twentieth century have persisted in the mistake for a
> long time.

Comment: What exactly don't you understand about this sentence? It is grammatically quite involved, but those two words mean exactly what you would expect. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/thus - in this way https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/understand  to know the meaning of something

Comment: @JavaLatte Of course I get the meaning of the two words, but I don't know their function in this particular sentence.

Comment: @HassanBashiri Look at a simplified sentence. Do you understand the following? *Milk spoilage **thus understood** leads to better storage planning.* If you understand that, then you understand the function of *thus understood*, and your confusion over the paragraph isn't due to the phrase itself.

Comment: @HassanBashiri Note that, in that paragraph, I have an issue with the grammar of the sentence within which *thus understood* is used. The sentence itself doesn't make sense to me—although the phrase does.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious paradox which makes the thesis of man’s animal origin thus understood actually serve idealism

thus understood = understood in this manner or in this way.

If you use understood in this manner or way, the sentence should be clearer for you.

It's adverbial

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather convoluted sentence (you can read the entire article [here](https://www.marxists.org/archive/seve/works/1974/ch3/3.1.3.htm)), but I think it breaks down like this:

- The obvious paradox which makes [the thesis] ... actually serve idealism ...
- the thesis of man’s animal origin
- the thesis thus understood
- [the paradox] has already been pointed out by A. Leroi-Gourhan.

So the part you've picked out is qualifying the thesis - it is not just any thesis of man's animal origins, it is the particular thesis that is understood because of something in a preceding sentence.

A more direct phrasing might be something like this:

> An obvious paradox in this thesis of man's animal origins makes it actually serve idealism, as already pointed out by A. Leroi-Gourhan.

Comment: You can edit your answer by making any change; for instance, by making "So the part you've picked out is qualifying the thesis - it is not just any thesis... etc." into two separate sentences. Once you make any change, my credit for editing your answer will disappear, which I prefer.